# В базе данных уже существует объект с именем "AspNetUsers"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, миграция, asp.net-identity-2

Есть БД. При проектировании выяснилось что `asp.net Identity` позволяет воспользоваться своими таблицами для авторизации и пр. В моем случае это таблица `AspNetUsers`. Я хотел добавить в него два своих поля - `ФИО` и `почта`(через override)
При выполнении миграции выдает ошибку - типа уже есть такая таблица, а я хочу всего лишь добавить поля в него. Где я допустил ошибку?

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser // father (Standard)
    {
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "ФИО")]
        public string Fio { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Почта")]
        public override string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    }

 public class HomebankContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Admins { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {



            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<RequestUser>()
                .HasKey(t => new
                {
                    t.RequestId,
                    t.UserId
                });


            modelBuilder.Entity<RequestUser>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Request)
                .WithMany(p => p.RequestUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RequestId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<RequestUser>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
                .WithMany(t => t.RequestUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserId);
        }
```

Comment: Вполне возможно проблема в том что поле email уже есть в таблице

Comment: Как миграция выглядит и как были созданны уже существующие таблицы?